# Eclipse - Using classes from another java project but same package for testing purposes

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, project, package

I have one project `CLRS` with the package `sorts`, within which I have created a few classes and interfaces for some elementary sorting algorithms. I'm now looking into a jUnit tutorial to implement some unit testing on the methods. The tutorial specifies I should separate my test files from my actual classes by placing them in another project. As such, I have created the project `CLRS Tests`. I've created a file `Test.java` within this project (under the package `sorts`). In this file, I'm trying to make sure I can actually instantiate the classes from the other project. As such, my `Test.java` file contains the following code:

```
package sorts;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sort<Integer> Sorter = new InsertionSort<>();
    }

}
```

This gives me the following compilation errors:

```
Sort cannot be resolved to a type
InsertionSort cannot be resolved to a type
```

The code itself is correct, as I have a similar file within the `CLRS` project which does the same thing and it works - so it's a problem with using two different projects.

The classes/interface have been created as follows:

```
public class InsertionSort<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Sort<T> {...}
public class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ISort<T> {...}
public interface ISort<T extends Comparable<T>> {...}
```

As you can see, they are all `public` so I'm not sure what the issue could be. Help appreciated :) .

Answer (score 0):

A public class, though it sounds as if it would be, DOES NOT go across projects. It does mean, though, that it can be accesed by classes in the same project. Private methods can not be called outside of it's own class. Static means that no mater how many times you initialize a new version of the class, it will always do the same thing.

The project is a seperate file in which eclipse stores your packages / librarys / classes / resources. The projects themselves are not part of the java code. When you run a code, it is compiled and runs in it's own file, and usualy is static (The code itself never changes) but some things (Like geting a file from outside of the java project, like a picture, will still work, though I don't recomend it, due to the fact that if the file is moved, it will become null, because the file won't be found.) can be changed/accesed.

To use your class in another java project, you should right click the class, copy it, right click the other class and paste.

Your question makes it sound like you are trying to use it to test slices of code. If this is what you are doing, you should just copy and paste the code that you want to implement in the other class(es).

If you really want a piece of code that you are going to use many times, you can make a Java Library (Jar) which is a colections of classes not meant to run on there own, and be used multiple times in many projects. For more information on how to do this, look [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/build-a-java-library-for-yourself/), [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-javalibrary/j-javalibrary.html), or [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=142428).

Comment: The thing is, I have made the same package under the second project. So is this not treated as the same package then? Does it shadow the original package?

Comment: No. The package in a seperate folder completely. Like on your computer, there are many directorys called desktop for each user, but that doesn't mean each user's desktop is the same. Also, even if 2 users have a text document with the same name on their desktop, the files still aren't the same. A package is a seporate directory.